# JSON Encoded array in jquery

Tags: jquery, json, cakephp-2.1

I have written jquery function as follows.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".voteup").click(function() {
    $.getJSON('<?php echo $this->Html->url(array('controller'=>'users', 'action'=>'vote', 'up')); ?>/'+<?php echo $movie['Movie']['id']; ?>, 
        function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(key, value) {
            alert(value);
        });
    });
  });
```

In view action I am doing like this.

```
echo json_encode($rating);
```

The array looks like.

```
array(
       'MovieRating' => array(
            'id' => '1',
            'thumbs_up' => '10',
            'total_votes' => '20',
        )
    )
```

How to get that array in jquery?

Comment: Note that in JS it won't be an array, it'll be an object with one property that is itself an object with three properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the php function json_encode: http://php.net/manual/de/function.json-encode.php.